# How do you format numbers called from an API in Django?

Tags: python, django, api, format

I have some values called from an API in a course I'm doing which I would like to format improve visibility. What is the best way to code this? Thanks. Example code is below:

`${{list_item.marketCap}}  {{list_item.ytdChange}}%`

Where, the first one I would like to add a comma for thousands and 2dp, and the second times by 100?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the first one to 2dp with a comma like so...

```
 {{  "{:,.2f}".format(float(list_item.marketCap))  }}
```

And to get the second item * 100 you simply return...

```
 {{  float(list_item.ytdChange) * 100 }}
```

Hopefully that works for you!

Comment: Many thanks Lee. I think the API output is a string as the code isn't working, how can I make it a float?

Comment: You should cast the items to float like so float(list_item.marketCap). i will update the code

Answer (score 0):

There are two options that I would suggest:

---

1. You either want to make a new [template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/custom-template-tags/) that formats your Django variable.
   The template tag will simply be a function created by you taking your variable into account and return the formatted value.

---

2. The second option consist of formatting the variables before the view is rendered and add it in the `context` of the `render` view return statement.

---

For the format function, there is nothing really complicated here. You can just use string concatenation or the [Python String Interpolation](https://realpython.com/python-string-formatting/#3-string-interpolation-f-strings-python-36).

## Here's an example:

```py
def format_thousands(value):
    return f'{value:,}' # Using Python ≥3.6

def format_two_decimals(value):
    return round(value, 2)
```

For more information on `context` and `views`, please refer to the [Django Doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/) since it is the basic stuff not related to that question.